# Rendering an image with requests without saving the image

Tags: python-3.x, image, flask, request

I have a code which which fetches company logos from clearbit API. Please find the code below:

```
url = "https://logo.clearbit.com/shopify.com"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I need to render it as an image instead of text. Please help me

Comment: Please read [ask] and make sure your code is a [mre].

Comment: Hi Baduker, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image is binary data. You will find the following solution in the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content).

```
url = 'https://logo.clearbit.com/shopify.com'
resp = requests.get(url)
resp.raise_for_status()
data = resp.content
```